# How can masonry plugin sort a brick wider then a columnWidth?

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

The masonry plugin stacks a brick into columns. It's a reorder of bricks to minimize the columns. How can it sort the bricks that are wider then the column width?

Comment: would you like to put some extra spaces between bricks(each column)?

Comment: No, I would like to know how it work?

Comment: There is an anecdote about filling a glass jar with rocks, pebbles, soil and sand, which specifies the correct packing algorithm to use. Big stuff first, then smaller, then smaller, then smallest. The anecdote is typically used to explain how to prioritize your time.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think my question is clear enough. The problem is that sometimes either the glass jar is too small and the rock is too big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's using a k-d tree or binary tree or a treemap algorithm. It's also called 2d bin-packing algorithm: http://www.codeincomplete.com/posts/2011/5/7/bin_packing/